# R Shiny developing app : ERROR con is not a connection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to understand how to upload files on a Shiny app.
I don't understand why my code doesn't word. Here is the server :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    readLines(input$file$datapath)  
  })  
}
```

I get the following error "readLines : con is not a connection", 
Could someone help me understand please ?

Comment: Just guessing, can you add `if(is.null(input$file$datapath)) return(NULL)` before the `readLines` line?

Comment: You can try to add `req(input$file$datapath)` before `readLines`: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html

Comment: I tried to add if(is.null(input$file$datapath)) return(NULL) but I still had the same error of connection.

Comment: Nevertheless, I managed to find a solution ! I checked the general options of Rstudio, and changed the directory. Thank you for your answers !